# How to output the excit code after the function finished

Tags: function, sh, exit-code

If in a shell script. There are two function with loop, and I run both function in the script and put both in the background.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function a {
  for 1 in 2; do
    if 3.sh; then
       echo 'done'
    else
       exit 1
    fi
  done
}

function b {
  for a in b; do
    if c.sh; then
       echo 'done'
    else
       exit 1
    fi
  done
}

a &
b &
```

Now since both functions are in background, once I run the script it will be completed right away. What I expected was to capture the exit code of the script so if anything wrong happened during loop a and b I can become acknowledged.

My another concern is that if anything happened during loop a, the script will be terminated right away (since exit code 1 is given), so b got terminated as well even if it's innocent.

Comment: There's no real reason to use `exit` instead of `return`; since the function is the only thing running in the background job, the background process will exit as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wait on a background job, the exit status of `wait` will be the exit status of the job.

```
a & a_pid=$!
b & b_pid=$!

wait $a_pid
a_status=$?
wait $b_pid
b_status=$?
```

You might object that if `b` finishes before `a`, then you have to wait to get `b`'s status. That *might* be a problem, but only if you have anything else to do. Regardless of which job finishes first, the time it takes for *both* to complete is the same. (If `b` does finish first, then `wait $b_pid` will exit immediately once it is run.)